# A tool to tell you what source files are needed in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction

I am porting a large, messy, 10 year old cold base in C++ from Metrowerks on OS X to XCode. There are so many files and all the other people that touched this over the years are gone. Nobody know what files are actually needed and which are just cruft.

Is there any tool that I could run and have it produce a list of what files are ACTUALLY needed?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Codewarrior can export Makefiles. Do you still have access to a copy of Codewarrior? For that matter, I think BBEdit used to be able to read CW project files - maybe it still can?

Comment: @Seth, yes, I have the entire old cold base and Codewarrior

Comment: This should be tagged "archaeology", I think.

Comment: @Seth - MW 8 is the version, I dont see an option to Export to a MakeFile, but I could export the Whole project, but that would be to much. BBEdit doesn't see any MW stuff as readable. .mcp, mch, etc

Comment: Are you talking about project specific files or C++ specific files or C++ related binaries? Posting a list of all the file extensions you find might help to focus the question.

Comment: I haven't used Codewarrior since v4 - I may be thinking of another compiler of that era (THINK C maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) on your project and have it generate inheritance diagrams for your classes. It can also generate caller graphs to help you find dead code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching this [static code analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) list in Wikipedia. The ones that I've seen in actions would be [cppdep](http://github.com/yuzhichang/cppdep) and [Include Hierarchy Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/includefinder.aspx), although the first one is a little rough and the latter is a Windows analyzer only for the include tree. Also that still might not give you all the info if the dependencies are not explicit.

**Edit:** Also, the following StackOverflow search query seems to have results that might interest you:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+dependency